# Hovering over image make anchor underneath unclickable

Tags: css

is there any way i can make anchor clickable without js?

I've tried changing z-index, display:none, nothing seems to work.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <a href="#">Random Text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: red;
}

.top:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sokvtqdn/)

Comment: Hi Mathew, welcome to SO! Instead of using `z-index: 20` hide the `<a>` first (or make its color transparent) and show or color the `<a>` when the image is hovered. Like `.bottom { color: rgba(0,0,0,0) } .top:hover+.bottom { color: rgba(0,0,0,1) }` using a sibbling (+) selector. Check [W3S: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Somehow i still can't make it. Removing `z-index` prevent hover from working. As for adding color and removing it, makes text transparent. But as hover doesn't work, it can't change texts color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slightly change your CSS to make it work.

If you would use the `wrapper` element for capturing the hover state, you could change the `z-index` of the `top` element to `0`, which brings the `bottom` element containing the anchor to the top.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top, .bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper:hover > .top {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```